# How to do mod_rewrite particular directory to root using htacess file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

MY hosting has disabled virtual directory mapping so i need to use mod_rewrite .
please guide me how to do .  I want to map http://example.com/folder/dashboard.php   to  http://example.com/dashboard.php

Answer (score 0):

In the htaccess file in your document root, add:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond $1 !^folder/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /folder/$1 [L]
```

And then make sure all your links look like `http://example.com/dashboard.php`